# _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: 1045, "Access denied for user

Tags: python, mysql

I want to connect to my database from Python shell

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="milenko",passwd="********",db="classicmodels")
```

But

```
 File "/home/milenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'milenko'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

I have created user

```
 CREATE USER 'milenko'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '8888888';
```

but still the problem is still there.
Databases

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| ap1                |
| classicmodels      |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What does this mean?How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this generally means you do not have permissions to access the server from that particular machine. to fix it, either create user 'milenko'@'localhost' or 'milenko'@'%' using your root server user

OR

grant your user privileges on that particular db

Comment: okay, now you have to grant yourself permissions on classicmodels: `grant all privileges on classicmodels.* to 'youruser'@'localhost'; flush privileges;`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your local server (e.g WampServer) is turned on.